# How to query SUMO ontology using SPARQL

Tags: java, sparql, jena, ontology

I'm using the [SUMO](http://www.ontologyportal.org/) ontology which I want to query with SPARQL. A typical entry in the SUMO, e.g., for a city, looks like this:

```xml
<owl:Thing rdf:ID="MadridSpain">
 <rdfs:isDefinedBy rdf:resource="http://www.ontologyportal.org/SUMO.owl"/>
 <rdf:type rdf:resource="#City"/>
 <owl:comment xml:lang="en">The City of Madrid in Spain.</owl:comment>
 <geographicSubregion rdf:resource="#Spain" />
 <externalImage rdf:datatype="xsd:anyURI">[...]</externalImage>
 <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">madrid spain</rdfs:label>
</owl:Thing>
```

If I want to get all cities from the ontology I use this example query (which works fine):

```java
String prefix = "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> "
              + "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>";
String rdq = prefix + "SELECT ?N ?O WHERE {?N rdf:type <http://www.ontologyportal.or/SUMO.owl#City>}";
```

My problem start when I want to filter the results. Suppose that I only want all cities which are a geographicSubregion of Spain. First I tried to solve that problem by analyzing all the results in Java and Jena which takes a huge amount of time (5-10s for each result, ~10000 results at all).

```java
Query myQuery = QueryFactory.create(rdq);
QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(myQuery, owlModel);
try {
 ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
 for (; results.hasNext();) {
  QuerySolution sol = results.nextSolution();
  Resource res = sol.getResource("N");
  StmtIterator it = res.listProperties();

  while(it.hasNext()){
   Statement state = it.next();
   //Doing some filtering
   System.out.println("predicate: " + state.getPredicate().toString());
   System.out.println("subject: " + state.getSubject().toString());
   System.out.println("object: " + state.getObject().toString());
  }
 }
}catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 System.err.println("Query Error " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Sure this isn't really effective and it must exist an easier way by using the right query. But at the moment I'm stuck at defining such a query. I tried the following ones, but none of them works.

```
SELECT ?N ?O WHERE { ?N rdf:type <http://www.ontologyportal.org/SUMO.owl#City> . 
 { SELECT ?N WHERE { (rdf:type ?b rdf:statement) .
 (rdf:Predicate ?b <http://www.ontologyportal.org/SUMO.owl#geographicSubregion>) .
 (rdf:Object ?b <http://www.ontologyportal.org/SUMO.owl#Spain>) } } }

SELECT ?N ?O WHERE { (rdf:statement ?b) .
 (rdf:Predicate ?b <http://www.ontologyportal.org/SUMO.owl#geographicSubregion>) . 
 (rdf:Object ?b <http://www.ontologyportal.org/SUMO.owl#Spain>) . }";
```

Does someone has an idea how to create a query which gets all cities within a country?

Comment: Have you made any progress on this?  I had brief exposure to SUMO a few years ago, and didn't know that there's an OWL translation, so this has been interesting to see.  If the answer so far didn't help, what other issues have you run into?

Comment: You solution works fine and +1 for the great answer.

Comment: Glad to be of help! As I said, I hadn't been aware of the OWL translation of SUMO, so this has been a nice piece of news for me.  Thanks for asking about it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took the RDF you presented to make a minimal RDF file that I could query against:

```xml
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.ontologyportal.org/SUMO.owl#"
         xml:base="http://www.ontologyportal.org/SUMO.owl"
         xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
         xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
         xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <owl:Thing rdf:ID="MadridSpain">
    <rdfs:isDefinedBy rdf:resource="http://www.ontologyportal.org/SUMO.owl"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#City"/>
    <owl:comment xml:lang="en">The City of Madrid in Spain.</owl:comment>
    <geographicSubregion rdf:resource="#Spain" />
    <externalImage rdf:datatype="xsd:anyURI">[...]</externalImage>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">madrid spain</rdfs:label>
  </owl:Thing>
</rdf:RDF>
```

SPARQL is a query language for matching data in RDF graphs.  The edges in an RDF graph are *triples*, simple statements of the form *subject predicate object*.  You were matching against a single triple.

```
?N rdf:type <http://www.ontologyportal.org/SUMO.owl#City>
```

Your query, as it is, will be easier to write if you define a prefix for `sumo:`, so we end up with  (also renaming `?N` to `?city`):

```
prefix sumo: <http://www.ontologyportal.org/SUMO.owl#>
select ?city where { 
  ?city rdf:type sumo:City .
}
```

That selects all the cities, as you've seen.  Now you just need to match an additional triple, so we just add it to the query:

```
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix sumo: <http://www.ontologyportal.org/SUMO.owl#>
select ?city where { 
  ?city rdf:type sumo:City .
  ?city sumo:geographicSubregion sumo:Spain .
}
```

To make this look nicer, two abbreviations can be applied.  First, in SPARQL, `rdf:type` can be written as `a`, because it's so common (and then we won't need to define the prefix, too).  Second, when you have multiple triples with the same subject, you can list the *predicate object* parts separated by a semicolon.  We end up with

```
prefix sumo: <http://www.ontologyportal.org/SUMO.owl#>
select ?city where { 
  ?city a sumo:City ;
        sumo:geographicSubregion sumo:Spain .
}
```

When I run this against the RDF above using Jena's command line tools, I get the following results:

```
$ arq --data sumo.rdf --query query.sparql
--------------------
| city             |
====================
| sumo:MadridSpain |
--------------------
```

#### Why the other queries didn't work

What you were trying to do in stuff like this

```
(rdf:type ?b rdf:statement) .
(rdf:Predicate ?b <http://www.ontologyportal.org/SUMO.owl#geographicSubregion>) .
(rdf:Object ?b <http://www.ontologyportal.org/SUMO.owl#Spain>)
```

was using the RDF reification vocabulary.  First, the syntax would need be to

```
?b a rdf:Statement ;
   rdf:subject ?city ;
   rdf:predicate sumo:geographicSubregion ;
   rdf:object sumo:Spain .
```

in order to match a reified triple of the form that you needed to answer your query.  However, this query requires that there be four triples in the graph of the specified form, and those *aren't* in the model.  Just because a triple is in the graph doesn't mean a reified version of it is.  (After all, since all the triples that are used to reify the first triple would also have to be reified, and then those ones would, and so on.)  SPARQL only lets you query the triples that are actually in the data.

Comment: Thank you for the great comment. Your solution works very fine. Thank you too for going the extra mile to explain my faults.